# Does a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module V imply a G-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

While I study representation theory, I have a question.
Let G be a group. Then,

> Does a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module V imply a G-module?

To see this, I tried to find a group homomorphism $\varphi : G \longrightarrow GL(V)$. For each $g\in G$, $\varphi(g)$ must be an invertible linear map. But, I'm failed to find the homomorphism. Please give me a hint!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **hint**: If $M$ is a (say, left) module over a ring $R$, then, for each $r \in R$, multiplication by $r$ induces an endomorphism of $M$, say $\mu_r$, with $\mu_r(m) = rm$. In your case $R=\mathbb C[G]$ and so this works in particular for all $g \in G$.

Remark:

1. In fact, in this way, you can equivalently characterize an $R$-module structure on $M$ as a ring homomorphism $R \to \operatorname{End}(M)$, $r \mapsto \mu_r$. Can you see how this is analogous to the description of a $G$-module structure by a group homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{GL}(M)?$
2. Your suspicion is correct, every $\mathbb C[G]$-module is a $G$-module. In fact, $G$-modules are the same thing as $\mathbb Z[G]$-modules.